# How to send a push notification to a subset of users that are anonymous?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm new to Parse, so apologies if this question is naïve ...
My iOS app doesn't ask users to sign-up, because sign-up is overkill and annoying for my app (ie. it has no sense of a "user"). When someone purchases a non-renewing subscription, then the app goes through Parse signup (via FB) and persists data on Parse, so that it is possible for the user to restore the subscription on other devices... but most users won't be buying subscriptions, so, most users will remain anonymous on Parse.

Here is the question: is it possible to send a push notification to:

A) *only* the users who did *not* purchase the subscription (ie. are anonymous on parse) ?

B) all users, including those who signed up and those who didn't?

As far as I can see, A) isn't possible because anonymous users cannot persist data on Parse?
Would like to know if i'm missing something.
Thanks.

**EDIT** - to make it more concrete, the reason I want to do A) is so I can send a push like "I realized my prices are too high, so I lowered them! go look!" :)

Comment: See my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/27321969/2353523

Comment: Thanks -- that's indeed the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anonymous users can save data into parse if you allow them to. In this case you need to look at the [`PFInstallation`](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFInstallation.html) class and consider subclassing it and / or connecting it to your `User` class (to allow you to query only installations whose users have a subscription). If you have already been doing some testing then installations will exist, you just can't usually see them in the web interface. You need to write code to use / connect the installations with user details.

Note* you might have multiple users connected to multiple devices...